# React native recieve shared link in app from safari browser (IOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, share

I am trying to build a simple application using react native.

I want to be able to share a link from IPhone Safari and open the link in my react-native applcation.

So far I tried these extension samples and it didn't work for ios (works with android though):

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share
https://github.com/meedan/react-native-share-menu

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: i dont think the first npm package works for your case, as you aren't trying to share something from your app to other social apps. you may want to take a look at [deep linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking).

Comment: @kenmistry need a user to be able to share a link with me from any site, not by navigating...
Receiving share intent on Android works with react-native-share-menu plugin

Comment: i think deep linking is something you should be looking at if you want a user to open a link from the mobile browser and open up your RN app from there to access/read that link.